# Cannot import Zlib in Python 3.5 on Wily

Tags: python, python3

After an upgrade to Wily, the new Python 3.5 package seems to be broken. I've tried doing a complete re-install of all the Python3 packages but it's not fixed the problem:

```
sal@gruntyman:~/workspace/ladygeek$ python3.5
Python 3.5.0 (default, Sep 15 2015, 21:54:38) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import zlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'zlib'
>>>
```

I don't think there's any problem with the actual C zlib library. I can import the same module in Python 3.4 and Python 2.7 without any problems.

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

**Edit 0**

```
sal@gruntyman:~/workspace/ladygeek$ apt-cache policy python3.5
python3.5:
  Installed: 3.5.0-3
  Candidate: 3.5.0-3
  Version table:
 *** 3.5.0-3 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Did you install all the updates? On my computer, when I run `python3.5` it says: `Python 3.5.0+ (default, Oct 11 2015, 09:05:38)` and `[GCC 5.2.1 20151010] on linux`.

Comment: Which package do you think I should reinstall?

Comment: In answer to "did I install the updates" - yes, the system is fully apt-get upgraded.

Comment: `zlib` is a built-in module. It's integrated into the Python interpreter, located in package `python3.5-minimal`.

Comment: Please post the output of `apt-cache policy python3.5`.

Comment: Added the output above - unfortunately apt-get install --reinstall python3.5-minimal does not fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that there was a rogue version of python in /usr/local/bin that was taking priority over Ubuntu's version. The solution was to remove this and allow Ubuntu's version to be the default.